# Exporting texture as png after coloring OBJ

Tags: blender, texture-mapping, meshlab

I imported an OBJ into MeshLab to do some coloring to it. I have the coloring, and every time I load the OBJ into MeshLabs, it has the color. When exporting my finished colored OBJ, I also got the .mtl file. However, for my uses, I can only use a texture PNG for coloring/texturing the OBJ..

So my question is.. Are there any ways within MeshLabs to export the colors I have added to my object as a texture PNG file?

If not, is it possible to do this within another program? Such as Blender? I am basically wanting to color an OBJ myself, and then somehow get those colors I added as a texture PNG. Not even sure if it's possible!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so it's off topic here.

Comment: I don't know much about meshlab, I expect the texturing you are doing is using vertex painting. You can use blender to do image texture painting. If your existing vertex colours import into blender you can [bake the vertex colours to an image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35159/935).